# How to check existence of a file from source directory in installshield 2021?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I need to add a file existence condition in installshield 2021 and the file is in the source directory of setup. I tried accessing it using path variable but I guess while validating exit condition, path variables are not initialized or set. Is there any way to add the condition in UI? (Without MSI or installscript)

For example, my setup directory will look like this and each folder is a package in issuite. I need to check whether a file in second folder is exists inside the exit condition.

[image]

(Since I am new to IS, I cant find other ways to do this one). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean to check if file exists in .msi file?

Comment: Hi, That's a file inside Packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I achieved this with [GetCurrentDir] in the exit condition. Hope this helps someone

Comment: [ORIGINALSETUPEXEDIR] worked for me.